# How to assign a group to user programmatically on registration

Tags: php, magento-1.8, user-roles

I would like to assign role to users on registration from my module.

I checked the `createPostAction()` method of `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class where i found these lines:

```
$customer->save();
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
);
```

Can i use event/observer ['customer_register_success'] to assign the group?
Should i create an event observer class in my module or there are better approaches?

Comment: What do you mean by "a role"?

Comment: Sorry i mean Group ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this from the backend.

Go to `System > Configuration > Customers > customer configuration > Create new account options` and choose the group you want to assign to in the `Default Group` option

[image: Set up default group]

This way you don't need to change any code. If you do however want to use code for some specific reason the `customer_register_success` event is the way to go.

Your observer would look something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function set_group($observer)
    {
        try {

            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

            $customer->setData('group_id', 2); // or whatever the group id should be
            $customer->save();

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will use your second solution because i need assign different groups based on data provided at registration.

Comment: I figured something like that :) glad to have helped

Comment: If you have to change the group after some other events you should get       the $customer like this: $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();